# Screen resolution based: Setting button's width and height

Tags: wpf, xaml

I'm starting to use WPF and I want to make an equivalent assignation just as in c# but I can't find how.

On my C# Windows Forms I usually use:

```cs
myButton.Width = (Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height * 6) / 100;

myButton.Height = (Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height * 6) / 100;
```

Now in XAML I'm using

```xml
<Button x:Name="myButton"/>
```

And then in my C# file I implement the C# code above.
But of course changes are not shown in the XAML editor

I tried something like:

```xml
<Button Width="{Binding Source={x:Static SystemParameters.WorkArea}, Path=Height * 0.06}" />
```

```xml
<Button Width="{Binding Source={x:Static SystemParameters.WorkArea}, Path=(Height * 0.06)}" />
```

```xml
<Button Width="({Binding Source={x:Static SystemParameters.WorkArea}, Path=Height}) * 0.06" />
```

```xml
<Button Width="{{Binding Source={x:Static SystemParameters.WorkArea}, Path=Height * 0.06} * 0.06}" />
```

etc. but none of it works.

How can I use a variable to set a Button's Width/Height directly from XAML code?

Comment: _"On my c# WinForms I usually use"_ -- there's your problem right there. You will fail miserably if you approach WPF the same way you approach Winforms. The only part that is even remotely similar is that both APIs support data binding, but even there many if not most Winforms programmers barely use data binding if at all, and WPFs data binding infrastructure is far more sophisticated, and warrants approaching it with a fresh viewpoint. As far as the specific issue, XAML doesn't do math unless you extend it with a markup extension, converter, etc.

Comment: For your particular scenario, you might consider just setting the value directly in a view model object. You should be learning and using MVVM anyway. Alternatively, use any of the robust and extensive layout objects found in WPF to handle the arrangement of controls for you. As an example: if you use `ColumnWidth="6*"` and `ColumnWidth="94*"` for adjacent columns in a `Grid` object, the `"6*"` column will have the width within the grid that you want for your button. You can combine this with other layout objects to arrange everything exactly as you want.

Comment: I would suggest you read a bit more about the WPF and XAML ecosystem. It is a powerful and somewhat complex beast, but definitely worth the effort of learning it. In a few words, WPF follows the principle of keeping the design and visual logic separated from the code as much as possible. Because of this, you end up using mainly bindings and panels to build your layouts. It is rare to use sizes like the WorkArea in WPF layouts. I think, whatever you wish to do, there is probably a better way. You may prefer to use a panel, like the Grid, Dock, or a combination of panels.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot do calculations in XAML.

Best way is to create an `IValueConverter`

[EDIT] and maybe pass in the factor as an `ConverterParameter`

[EDIT2] But maybe this isn't really the way you want to go. Maybe you want a `Grid` with relative column and row widths/heights and put the button in there and stretch it. This is more the way you work in WPF. Use layout components instead of fixed positioning and sizing

Answer (score 1):

Of course you can set the `Width` and `Height` of your button in code-behind via its name, e.g.:

```
<Button x:Name="myButton"/>
```

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
   public MainWindow()
   {
      InitializeComponent();

      myButton.Width = (Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height * 6) / 100;
      myButton.Height = (Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height * 6) / 100;
   }

   // ...other code.
}
```

You cannot do this directly in XAML as these kind of expressions are not supported. However, you can create a custom value converter with a factor as parameter that calculates the value.

```
public class FactorConverter : IValueConverter
{
   public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
   {
      return (double)value * System.Convert.ToDouble(parameter, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
   }

   public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
   {
      return (double)value / System.Convert.ToDouble(parameter);
   }
}
```

You have to create a converter instance in a resource dictionary in XAML, e.g. the `Window` resources.

```
<Window ...>
   <Window.Resources>
      <local:FactorConverter x:Key="FactorConverter"/>
   </Window.Resources>
   <!-- ...other markup. -->
</Window>
```

You need a `Binding` instead of the `Static` markup extension to use the converter.

```
<Button x:Name="myButton"
        Width="{Binding Source={x:Static SystemParameters.WorkArea}, Path=Height, Converter={StaticResource FactorConverter}, ConverterParameter='0.06'}"
        Height="{Binding Source={x:Static SystemParameters.WorkArea}, Path=Height, Converter={StaticResource FactorConverter}, ConverterParameter='0.06'}"/>
```

Note that the `ConverterParameter` is passed as `string` and then converted to `double` in the converter. To pass it directly as `double` you would need to write a custom markup extension or write the binding in a much more verbose way, e.g. for `Width`:

```
<Button x:Name="myButton">
   <Button.Width>
      <Binding Source="{x:Static SystemParameters.WorkArea}"
               Path="Height"
               Converter="{StaticResource FactorConverter}">
         <Binding.ConverterParameter>
            <system:Double>0.06</system:Double>
         </Binding.ConverterParameter>
      </Binding>
   </Button.Width>
</Button>
```

This way, you could  just cast `parameter` to `double` instead of using `Convert.ToDouble`.